# SVG Absolute coordinates?

Tags: svg, position, coordinates, coordinate-transformation

I have some SVG files which have many text nodes in them.

I would like to get the absolute position of each of the text nodes, within the SVG document (the SVG documents have width="743.75" and height="1052.5").

An example text node looks like this:

```
 <g>
  <text transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,106.5,732.5)">
   <tspan x="0 7.8979998 14.003 17.698999" y="0">Date</tspan>
  </text>
 </g>
```

How can I calculate all of the matrix() transforms to arrive at the positive absolute X and Y values for each text box? Is there a simple recursive function I could use and pass in each matrix in turn?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am also trying to solve this problem, except for images.  The question of recursion is that you need to dot multiply the transformation matricies.  I'm using NumPy.  However, my computations are coming up with ostensibly incorrect answers.  Maybe you'll have more luck.

[Link](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html)

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformMatrixDefined

```
from decimal import Decimal
import xml.dom.minidom as dom
from numpy import *
doc = dom.parse("labels.svg")

def walk(node):
    if node.nodeType != 1:
        return
    if node.tagName == 'image':
        href = node.getAttribute('xlink:href')
        if not href.startswith("labels/"):
            return
        name = (
            href.
            replace('labels/', '').
            replace('.png', '').
            replace('-resized', '').
            replace('-normalized', '')
        )
        left = float(node.getAttribute('x'))
        top = float(node.getAttribute('y'))
        position = matrix([left, top, float(1)])
        width = float(node.getAttribute('width'))
        height = float(node.getAttribute('height'))
        size = matrix([left, top, float(1)])
        transform = node.getAttribute('transform')
        if transform:
            a, b, c, d, e, f = map(float, transform
                .replace('matrix(', '')
                .replace(')', '')
                .split(',')
            )
            transform = matrix([
                [a, c, e],
                [b, d, f],
                [0, 0, 1]
            ])
            left, top, _ = (transform.I * position.T).A1
        print name, (left, top)
    child = node.firstChild
    while child:
        walk(child)
        child = child.nextSibling

walk(doc.documentElement)
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont have much time to refine this answer, but this worked for me to convert svg coordinates to an absolute position

```
//this will convert an x, y coordinate within a viewBox - or not in one at all (I think) - to an absolute position on the document
//my <svg>...</svg> element had a viewbox on it and it still worked...
convertCoords: function(svgElement, elementToConvert, x, y) {

    var element_x = elementToConvert.getBBox().x;
    var element_y = elementToConvert.getBBox().y;
    var offset = svgElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    var matrix = elementToConvert.getScreenCTM();

    return {
        x: (matrix.a * x) + (matrix.c * y) + matrix.e - offset.left,
        y: (matrix.b * x) + (matrix.d * y) + matrix.f - offset.top
    };
},
```

and to actually use the code to do useful stuff:

```
svgGraphLibObject.convertCoords(mysvg, allCircleElements[0], allCircleElements[0].getBBox().x, 0)
```

where mysvg is the container element. i.e.

```
var mysvg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
```

allCircleElements[0] is the actual element to allCircleElements[0].getBBox().x is the x position that will be converted later to an absolute position and finally, the last parameter (i.e. 0) is the y position to be converted to an absolute position

hope it helps anyone in the future

stay blessed